# MySQL Select rows by a key or fall back to select by default key

Tags: mysql, sql, translation

I have the following language table in MySQL to select text in different languages.

```
CREATE TABLE `lang` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`group` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`text` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`language` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'def',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE INDEX `group_language` (`group`, `language`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

The table contains the following data

```
id  group  text               language
1   1      This is English    def
2   2      Helo sir           def
3   3      how are you?       def
4   3      Wie geht es dir?   de
```

The group field tells me what texts belong together for each translation.
In the above example group '3' has a default text (English) and a German translation.

Now I want to select all texts for German and if they don't exist, I will want to have the fallback English text for that.

Anybody an idea how I can put that together into a SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT
        COALESCE(b.ID, a.ID) ID,
        COALESCE(b.`GROUP`, a.`GROUP`) `GROUP`,
        COALESCE(b.`text`, a.`text`) `text`,
        COALESCE(b.language, a.language) language
FROM   TableName a
       LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID, `GROUP`, `text`, language
            FROM tableName
            WHERE language = 'de'
         ) b ON a.ID <> b.ID AND a.`GROUP` = b.`GROUP`
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2157b/10)

Comment: i think this code is better:
SELECT  
        COALESCE(b.ID, a.ID) ID,
        COALESCE(b.`GROUP`, a.`GROUP`) `GROUP`,
        COALESCE(b.`text`, a.`text`) `text`,
        COALESCE(b.language, a.language) language
FROM   TableName a
       LEFT JOIN
            FROM tableName b 
ON b.language = 'de' and a.language='def' AND a.`GROUP` = b.`GROUP`

Answer (score 2):

The following query will do a LEFT JOIN of the lang table with itself where the first set of columns will hold values corresponding to the default language and second set holds the values for `de` language if present, nulls otherwise. You would select `de.text` if present, or use the default language text otherwise, using the standard `ISNULL` function.

```
SELECT IFNULL(de.text, def.text) 
FROM
    lang def
    LEFT JOIN lang de
    ON def.group = de.group AND def.language = 'def' AND de.language = 'de'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. As I can see from the MySQL documentation, 'ISNULL' takes only one argument:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull
So this does not work unfortunately :-(

Comment: It does however work with IFNULL. Thanks for the JOIN example, I have now managed to get it to work and will post the answer.

Comment: Ah! ISNULL is SQL Server's counterpart for IFNULL in MySQL. Thanks for the comment, I updated the answer, @lockdoc.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it seems to work this way. Thanks to Vikdor for providing the JOIN:

```
SELECT
    def.id,
    def.`group`,
    IFNULL(curr.`text`, def.`text`) AS `text`
FROM
    lang def
LEFT JOIN
    lang curr
ON
    def.`group` = curr.`group` AND
    def.`language` = 'def' AND
    curr.`language` = 'de'
GROUP BY
    def.`group`
```

Comment: this is wrong. The ID does not match with the original record [click here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2157b/14)