# Selecting the most appropriate row from a table for a specific locale

Tags: mysql

I am trying to design a [MySQL] query which will allow me to fetch items from a database and bring back the most appropriate item for a user's locale, and fall back to the system/default locale.

The ruleset for this query is:

1. An exact match
2. A language match, but different region
3. System default

Due to the system this is being implemented in, I have the following requirements:

- I cannot explicitly specify columns to select, so `COALESCE()` is probably not appropriate
- Sub queries are OK, perf is important, but I'd rather get the right content
- We can assume there will always be a row for the item in the system/default locale

I have tried writing various queries which incorporate a sub query but I can't quite find the logic.

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `foo_localised` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `language` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `region` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`language`,`region`),
  CONSTRAINT `foo_localised_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `foo` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Which contain the following rows:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` (`id`)
VALUES (1),(2),(3);

INSERT INTO `foo_localised` (`id`, `language`, `region`, `label`)
VALUES
  (1, 'en', 'GB', 'I only wear trousers to a wedding'),
  (1, 'en', 'US', 'I only wear pants to a wedding'),
  (1, 'es', 'ES', 'Solo llevo pantalones para una boda'),
  (2, 'en', 'GB', 'Good day, sir'),
  (2, 'es', 'ES', 'Hola, amigo'),
  (3, 'en', 'GB', 'My name is Pablo'),
  (3, 'de', 'DE', 'Ich heiße Pablo');
```

The expected results for the following locales would be as follows (default being `en_GB`):

```
en_GB
1, I only wear trousers to a wedding
2, Good day, sir
3, My name is Pablo

en_US
1, I only wear pants to a wedding
2, Good day, sir
3, My name is Pablo

es_ES
1, Solo llevo pantalones para una boda
2, Hola, amigo
3, My name is Pablo

de_DE
1, I only wear trousers to a wedding
2, Good day, sir
3, Ich heiße Pablo
```

Comment: Could you clarify your first 2 restrictions (and the "probably" in it?). The [obvious choice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13485448) is to use 2-3 left joins and coalesce (and since you mentioned coalesce, you might have tried it already), and if there is some restriction, naivly I would assume you should be able to do it in a subquery (e.g. `select * from (select coalesce(...` or `select (select coalesce(...) ...) as value from ...`). Could you add an example as to how a query could look like and how not, as that seems to be the complicated part of this question.

Comment: @solarflare - by "probably" I mean I don't think it is appropriate, but I'm doubting myself due to inexperience. I essentially need my `SELECT` to be `*`, I can add to the `SELECT`, but it's not practical for me to list each column because it is an abstract class and the class which will implement it could have any shape (in addition to `id`, `language` and `region`. Second restriction is that I'm happy to add sub queries even at a performance cost, but I'm not sure how much cost is too much. Does that make sense/help?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not really help. It feels like you are trying to presolve a problem that may not actually exist (it happens when oop meets sql). The sql problem (which make up 98% of your question) is solved in the link, while your problems with that code and your special requirements and thus any solution to it are still unclear. Could you a) try that code and name some concrete problems you encounter with it (that we might be able to adapt to your requirements) and/or b) add one of your queries, which, while incorrect, might give us an idea how your queries should look like.

Comment: @Solarflare - I worked out a solution and have posted it as an answer. Maybe it helps clarifies my question? If you're so inclined, I'd love your opinion on it as someone who is likely more knowledgable than me.

Answer (score 0):

So, I worked out the following query which does what I wanted to achieve.

It assumes a request for an item in Spanish (Spain), and a default of English (UK). It will provide Spanish (Spain) results, then Spanish results (e.g. Spanish (Mexico)) and finally, English (UK).

```sql
SELECT 
    fl.*,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo_localised fl1 WHERE fl1.id = fl.id AND fl1.language = 'es' AND fl1.region = 'ES') exists_exact,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM foo_localised fl2 WHERE fl2.id = fl.id AND fl2.language = 'es' AND fl1.region != 'ES') exists_language

FROM foo f

LEFT JOIN foo_localised fl ON fl.id = f.id

HAVING

-- Return the row if the "group" has an exact match, and _this_ is the exact match
(exists_exact = 1 AND `language` = 'es' AND `region` = 'ES')

-- Return the row if the "group" has an alternative language variant
OR (exists_exact = 0 AND `language` = 'es')

-- Return the row if there is no exact or language row, and it is the default locale
OR (exists_exact = 0 AND exists_language = 0 AND `language` = 'en' AND `region` = 'GB')
```

This query does not require me to know anything about the structure of the table (except for `id`, `language` and `region` of course).

Posting as a solution for others. It works well for my requirements, but I'm not 100% sure it is an efficient solution. Comments and feedback welcomed.